WebNFC NDEFReader is not a constructor
 const handleRead = async() => {
    addLog("User clicked scan button");
    if ('NDEFReader' in window) {
      console.log('NDEFReader is supported');
    } else {
      console.log('NDEFReader is not supported');
    }
    try{
      const ndef = new window.NDEFReader();
      await ndef.scan();
      addLog("> Scan started");
      ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", () => {
        addLog("Argh! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?");
      });
      ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber })=>{
        addLog(`> Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
        addLog(`> Records: (${message.records.length})`);
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        for(const record of message.records){
          if(record.recordType === "text")
            {
              const text = decoder.decode(record.data);
              addLog(`> Record text: ${text}`);
            }
        }
      }
        
      ); 
    }catch(error){
      addLog("Error: " + error)
    }
  }

when i try to change const ndef = new NDEFReader(); it will show the error: NDEFReader is not   'NDEFReader' is not defined  no-undef. But if i keep this, in the logerr shows NDEFReader is not a constructor.
I had google it but solution didnt work. I have been add the https in to my react project

Are you testing it on Android?
